# Getting white screen of death on category pages because of body_class() function

Tags: theme-development

Category pages "example.com/categeories/blah" were working fine and then suddenly started showing white screens.

Debug showed no output. No errors in apache logs either. So I started debugging with print statement and found the issue in `header.php` file: Commenting out `body_class` fixes the issue and the category pages load:

`<body <?php //body_class(); ?>>`

How might I find the root cause of this problem?

**UPDATE:** Commenting out this code in get_body_class() function fixes the problem, too:

```
            } elseif ( is_category() ) {
                        /*
                        $cat       = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                        $classes[] = 'category';
                        if ( isset( $cat->term_id ) ) {
                                $cat_class = sanitize_html_class( $cat->slug, $cat->term_id );
                                if ( is_numeric( $cat_class ) || ! trim( $cat_class, '-' ) ) {
                                        $cat_class = $cat->term_id;
                                }

                                $classes[] = 'category-' . $cat_class;
                                $classes[] = 'category-' . $cat->term_id;
                        }
                         */
```

**UPDATE 2**: This is really weird. If I drop a `echo '.'` statement right after the `$cat       = $wp_query->get_queried_object();` line in the portion of the `get_body_class` function shown above, everything works! If I do `echo ' '` instead, it breaks again! WTF???

**UPDATE 3**: This is also really weird. If I get rid of the echo statement and change the `$classes[] = 'category';` to `$classes[] = '';` the problem if fixed as well. In fact, if I change it to any other string, it works. So it only chokes when it is set to `category`. How weird is that?

Comment: I think this problem has to be related to they polylang module which creates different slugs for different categories. Deactivating the module did not fix things, though.

Comment: a white screen of death indicates a PHP error occurred. You need to open your PHP error log to find out what the actual problem is, or turn on error logging and recreate the problem again to get the error message. It's unlikely you'll find a solution with just what you've shared unless you know the error message. Also never modify WordPress core files in `wp-includes` or `wp-admin` under any circumstances, it can cause lots of issues and will all be undone when you update WordPress

Comment: As indicated, there are no errors. Not with debug, not in apache.

Comment: And yes, I turned on debug in wp-config.

Comment: `WP_DEBUG` isn't enough, and it won't be in the apache error log, it's in the PHP error log, PHP doesn't display error messages by default. It's possible you do not have the error log turned on or it's in an unexpected location, your host may be able to help with that, and there's the `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constant. You may also need to use view source to see it

Comment: I can see other PHP errors in apache logs. I am the host. It's a bug in WP. I found it. This ain't my first time at the rodeo. I know how to debug code.

Comment: Actually, not a bug in WordPress, a bug in CSS. Jesus. It was causing body to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out this bizarreness. My big mistake: assuming a white screen of death was some kind of code error with PHP. It was actually some badly coded css on my part that hid the entire body from view! All I had to do is look at the source code to see all the code was there.

So that explains why there were no errors and why throwing an echo statement that output to the screen magically "fixed" things; because it broke the css rendering.

One of those days.

And pro tip: don't work on 3 hours of sleep.